# How to pass an arraylist using sendKeys() method in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist, webdriver

```
org.openqa.selenium.By.WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
String array [] = {"21478","12458"};

   for(int i=0;i<=array.length-1;i++)
        {

      driver.findElement(By.id("cs")).sendKeys(array[i]);
        }
```

I want to pass above two array values into text box in selenium

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong? Does driver start? Does test fail? Or does test pass without entering the values into the text box? Please provide some more informations :)

Comment: Actually, when i run the script then above mentioned array values get concatenated like (21478+12458) into text box. i want to enter one value at a time and then enter other value.

Comment: If you mean to clear the field just before entering second value, please try using: driver.findElement(By.id("cs")).clear(); You can use it just before sendKeys() :)

Comment: I think it would help if you could explain what you're trying to do.  Do you want to enter the first value, have it execute whatever  logic you need, and then move on to the second value?  Or do you just want the text to have a space in the middle?

Comment: Actually, i want to run a loop which enter one value at a time(21478) and then enter second value (12458).

Answer (score 1):

As per your question to pass an *arraylist* using `sendKeys()` method you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  public class TEST {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          String array [] = {"21478","12458"};
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          for(int i=0;i<=array.length-1;i++)
          {
              driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(array[i]);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: sendKey_array]

Comment: Yes, but i want to enter one value at a time and after that the second value should get from loop.

Comment: @Ravinder That is what the solution does for you. What is your issue now?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to press Enter after each element, just add `+ "\n"` to the argument of the `sendKeys` method call.